# How to mock EF with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have been tasked at work to create a test script that will (using entity framework) look-up a value in a table if existing.

The code I have to work with has this constructor:

```
public PostProductHelper(
    Func<IMachineDBContext> contextFactory )
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}
```

My method to unit test could be something like this:

```
public string CheckAndRemoveProductNameFileExtIfExists(
    string productName )
{
    using ( var ctx = CreateContext() )
    {
        return ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault( d => d.Name == productName);
    }
}
```

so, going by the examples when Googling I am supposed to do this:

```
MockProductRepository = Substitute.For<IProductRepository>();
MockMessagePublicationService = Substitute.For<IMessagePublicationService>();
MockMachineDBContext = Substitute.For<IMachineDBContext>(););

var Products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Name = "BBB" },
    new Product { Name = "ZZZ" },
    new Product { Name = "AAA" },
}.AsQueryable();

MockMachineDBContext.Products.AddRange( Products );
```

But in order to pass to my constructor I have to modify this to:

```
MockProductRepository = Substitute.For<IProductRepository>();
MockMessagePublicationService = Substitute.For<IMessagePublicationService>();
MockMachineDBContext = Substitute.For<Func<IMachineDBContext>>();

var Products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Name = "BBB" },
    new Product { Name = "ZZZ" },
    new Product { Name = "AAA" },
}.AsQueryable();

MockMachineDBContext.Products.AddRange( Products );
```

which errors on the last line saying 'cannot resolve symbol 'Products'.

I am not allowed to change this constructor and I appreciate I may be making some mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing () after `MockMachineDBContext` in `MockMachineDBContext().Products.AddRange( Products );`

MockMachineDBContext is delegate.
For usage also see [Substituting for delegates in NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/).